# PostgreSQL trigger before update

Tags: postgresql

When I try to update, I receive an error. Any help is highly appreciated!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_x(value integer)
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

BEGIN
update backups.scrap_v16_sah_mil_hur_bak set value = '-99' where scrap_durum =1 and ( char_length(value) < 5 or  value= '' or  value is null or value  like '%Belir%'  ); 

    RETURN value;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;


ALTER FUNCTION test_x(value)
  OWNER TO postgres;

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION backups.scrap_v16_sah_mil_hur_bak(value) TO public;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION backups.scrap_v16_sah_mil_hur_bak(value) TO postgres;

CREATE TRIGGER test_x
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON  backups.scrap_v16_sah_mil_hur_bak
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_x();
```

The error message is

> ERROR: trigger functions cannot have declared arguments HINT: The
>   arguments of the trigger can be accessed through TG_NARGS and TG_ARGV
>   instead. CONTEXT: compilation of PL/pgSQL function "test_x" near line
>   1

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the declared function argument in

> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_x(**value integer**)

Triggers typically use $NEW and $OLD associative arrays containing the values of the new or old table row for INSERT or UPDATE actions, or empty for DELETE.

See complete example and explanation PL/PGSQL trigger  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/pltcl-trigger.html

Comment: İn this code I get data from another server. Firstly I get data from server later I check the incoming data. if the data has value lenght is less than five or empty I want to change new value. How can I do that? İn this way thanks your answer.